# Can't set borders correctly in styles in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of code which adds 8 custom styles to Excel and removes all others.
Most of the code works except for 1 bit. This concerns a style which has a colored border only on the bottom edge, the other edges have no border.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("Table top row")
   .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
   .Font.Size = 8
   .Font.Bold = True
   .Font.Italic = False
   .Font.Color = vbBlack
   .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(120, 159, 218)
   .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
   .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With
```

This piece of code results in the right font but no border at all.
I then tried it another way:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("Table top row")
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    .Borders.Color = RGB(120, 159, 218)
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With
```

This results in a border everywhere except the left edge. I'm absolutely puzzled to why I can't get this to work. Some solutions I've found include transforming a range instead of a style, but i need the style to quickly use in different files.

Comment: You can record the macro doing changes that you want and get the right code generated in the module.

Comment: I know that this comment is way late, but in this specific case, the comment by newguy is incorrect. The macro recorder will record the code using the constants shown in the question like xlEdgeRight. However these are the wrong constants, and will not work. The correct constants are the ones shown in the answer like xlRight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `xlRight` etc rather than `xlEdgeRight` etc. This seems to work, though I don't fully understand why.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("Table top row")
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    .Borders.Color = RGB(120, 159, 218)
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks